# Perl: Declaring a list of values as a constant

Tags: perl

I've been using the [constant] pragma, and have a quick question on how I can declare a constant list:

```
use constant {
   LIST_ONE   => qw(this that the other),    #BAD
   LIST_TWO   => ("that", "this", "these", "some of them"),   #BAR
   LIST_THREE => ["these", "those", "and thems"],   #WORKS
};
```

The problem with the last one is that it creates a reference to a list:

```
use constant {
   LIST_THREE => ["these", "those", "and thems"],
};

# Way 1: A bit wordy and confusing

my $arrayRef = LIST_THREE;
my @array = @{$arrayRef};

foreach my $item (@array) {
   say qq(Item = "$item");
}

# Way 2: Just plain ugly
foreach my $item (@{&LIST_THREE}) {

   say qq(Item = "$item");
}
```

This works, but it's on the ugly side.

Is there a **better** way of creating a constant list?

I realize that constants are really just a cheap way of creating a subroutine which returns the value of the constant. But, subroutines can also return a list too.

What is the best way to declare a constant list?

Comment: Perhaps you are aware, but in the examples you're declaring the *reference* to be a constant, rather than the list itself.  So you can assign values to items in the list and change them, like `LIST_THREE->[0] = "thoses";`.

Comment: @martinclayton - Yeah, I realized that not long after I wrote this. The reference is constant, but the value that reference is pointing to can change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html), if you do:

```
use constant DAYS => qw( Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday);
```

...you can then do:

```
my @workdays = (DAYS)[1..5];
```

I'd say that's nicer than the two ways of referencing constant lists that you have described.

Comment: Indeed, the documentation also says (my emphasis): "Instead of writing multiple `use constant` statements, you may define multiple constants in a single statement by giving, instead of the constant name, a reference to a hash where the keys are the names of the constants to be defined. *Obviously, all constants defined using this method must have a single value.*"

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - The program I used was a test program. I'm actually defining a bunch of constants in a single `use constant`. However, as you pointed out, I could simply add another `use constant` declaration and the whole thing will work. I missed the part you highlighted in your comment. Yes _obviously_ all the constants defined that way have to have a single value.

Answer (score 1):

The `constant` pragma is just syntactic sugar for a compile-time subroutine declaration. You can do more or less the same thing with a subroutine that returns a list with something like:

```
BEGIN {
    *LIST_ONE = sub () { qw(this that the other) }
}
```

And then you may say

```
@list = LIST_ONE;
$element = (LIST_ONE)[1];
```

Comment: There is no need for the glob assignment. `BEGIN {
    sub LIST_ONE() { qw(this that the other) };
}` is fine.

Comment: @mob - Yes, it's syntactic sugar, but it's still sweet. In the end, it's a subroutine. (which is why I could do `&LIST` to get the value of the reference. The syntactic sugar greatly improves readability, so I like it.

Comment: If you're not going to use a glob, then there's no need to say `BEGIN` either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constant array, I'd recommend using [Const::Fast](https://metacpan.org/module/Const::Fast), which lets you declare constant scalars, hashes, and arrays.

I've reviewed all the different modules on CPAN for declaring constants: http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html.

Neil

Comment: Problem with the review: Attribute::Constant's 'strange' syntax comes from it being tied to an attribute, but underneath it uses Data::Lock's "dlock", which has basically the same implementation and syntax as Const::Fast's "const" (i.e. it uses Internals::SvREADONLY() too)

Comment: MkV: updated the section on Attribute::Constant to mention Data::Lock and SvREADONLY -- thanks.